# Filter transactions by department

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database that is used for recording transactions by customers.

The table (transactions) is set out as follows:

```
ID | Added-date | userid | amount | department | transaction-date | addedby
1    yyyy-mm-dd   P1001    9.78     dpt 1        yyyy-mm-dd         username
1    yyyy-mm-dd   P1023    19.78    dpt 2        yyyy-mm-dd         username
1    yyyy-mm-dd   P1021    39.78    dpt 3        yyyy-mm-dd         username
1    yyyy-mm-dd   T1501    9.78     dpt 2        yyyy-mm-dd         username
```

What I would like to do is be able to view all of the users who have never bought anything in department x .

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is there a table of users? Or are we only interested in users who have not bought anything in department x but HAVE bought something in some other department?

Comment: I thought I had a clever way of doing it with ``MINUS``, but it isn't supported by MySQL. Thanks, @Strawberry.

Comment: Yes, there's a table of users, but all I'm interested in is finding users who have only ever bought something in one department and not another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.  I like the syntax of an `OUTER JOIN` / `NULL` check:

```
select distinct t.userid
from transactions t
    left join transactions t2 
        on t.userid = t2.userid and t2.department = 'Some Dept'
where t2.userid is null
```

`DISTINCT` may or may not be needed -- depends on your desired results.

You could also use `NOT IN` (but I have seen performance issues in MySQL with this):

```
select distinct userid
from transactions
where userid not in (
    select userid
    from transactions
    where department = 'Some Dept')
```

Comment: @user2475770 -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When you have just a few customer you can loop through all records and sort by field department in some order. Or you can group them by field department. For example a 2-dim array:

```
    $sort[$department][]=$record;
```

Then you can the filtering with another programming logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a subquery syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM transactions WHERE transactions.userid = users.id) = 0
```